# Maven error compiling for embedded class

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, maven, datanucleus

I have a data class `DPOSTerminalRecord`. I have an embedded data class inside it called `LimitedList`. I am using DataNucleus JDO for MongoDB with DN enhancer.

When doing a `mvn clean package` command, I'm getting the following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project MainProject: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/rhs/git/Project/MainProject/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/rhs/data/QDPOSTerminalRecord.java:[32,53] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class QLimitedList
[ERROR] location: class com.rhs.data.DPOSTerminalRecord
```

Any idea how I can resolve this? I do not see the `LimitedList` class inside the `QDPOSTerminalRecord.java` file. I do not have any issues with this in Eclipse compiling, only with Maven. In Eclipse the log shows that `com.rhs.data.DPOSTerminalRecord$LimitedClass` is being enhanced. What am I missing?

edit: Added a quick view of my class

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class DPOSTerminalRecord {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String _id; // this is the device ID

    private String _name; // this is the last logged name for the device

    @PersistenceCapable
    @EmbeddedOnly
    private static class LimitedList<E> // the limited list type automatically dumps the last object out of the list when the capacity is reached.
    {
        @Persistent
        int capacity;
        @Persistent
        private ArrayList<E> list;

        public LimitedList(int initialCapacity) {
            capacity = initialCapacity;
            list = new ArrayList<E>(capacity);
        }

        public boolean add(E e) 
        {
            if(list.size() == capacity)
            {
                // dump the last object
                list.remove(capacity - 1);
            }

            return list.add(e);
        }
    }

    @Embedded(members={
            @Persistent(name="capacity", column="capacity"),
            @Persistent(name="list", column="list")
    })
    @Persistent
    private LimitedList<String> m_knownNames = new LimitedList<String>(5);

    public DPOSTerminalRecord(String id, String name) {
        super();
        _id = id;
        _name = name;
    }
...etc
```

edit2: Added the generated class

```
package com.rhs.data;

import javax.jdo.query.*;
import org.datanucleus.api.jdo.query.*;

public class QDPOSTerminalRecord extends PersistableExpressionImpl<DPOSTerminalRecord> implements PersistableExpression<DPOSTerminalRecord>
{
    public static final QDPOSTerminalRecord jdoCandidate = candidate("this");

    public static QDPOSTerminalRecord candidate(String name)
    {
        return new QDPOSTerminalRecord(null, name, 5);
    }

    public static QDPOSTerminalRecord candidate()
    {
        return jdoCandidate;
    }

    public static QDPOSTerminalRecord parameter(String name)
    {
        return new QDPOSTerminalRecord(DPOSTerminalRecord.class, name, ExpressionType.PARAMETER);
    }

    public static QDPOSTerminalRecord variable(String name)
    {
        return new QDPOSTerminalRecord(DPOSTerminalRecord.class, name, ExpressionType.VARIABLE);
    }

    public final StringExpression _id;
    public final StringExpression _name;
    public final com.rhs.data.DPOSTerminalRecord.QLimitedList m_knownNames; // This is the infringing line since there is no QLimitedList inside this file

    public QDPOSTerminalRecord(PersistableExpression parent, String name, int depth)
    {
        super(parent, name);
        this._id = new StringExpressionImpl(this, "_id");
        this._name = new StringExpressionImpl(this, "_name");
        if (depth > 0)
        {
            this.m_knownNames = new com.rhs.data.DPOSTerminalRecord.QLimitedList(this, "m_knownNames", depth-1);
        }
        else
        {
            this.m_knownNames = null;
        }
    }

    public QDPOSTerminalRecord(Class type, String name, ExpressionType exprType)
    {
        super(type, name, exprType);
        this._id = new StringExpressionImpl(this, "_id");
        this._name = new StringExpressionImpl(this, "_name");
        this.m_knownNames = new com.rhs.data.DPOSTerminalRecord.QLimitedList(this, "m_knownNames", 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the problem is at `QDPOSTerminalRecord.java:[32,53]` - what's there? (I assume that's line 32, column 53...)

Comment: It's referencing `QLimitedList`. I've attached the generated source file under Edit2 for reference.

Comment: Okay, that makes things clearer. Do you *have* to use a nested class here? Could you just make it a top-level class? That feels like the simplest way of fixing the issue.

Comment: put LimitedList in a separate class file

Comment: Thanks! Extracting it out now works totally fine. Weird that it didn't work previously.. I wonder if we are not suppose to do that in the first place

Comment: well the docs i look at for JDO typesafe queries says that inline static persistable classes aren't supported